# How can i get element number from the TableLayout while clicking on item from the TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

How can I get element number from the Table Layout while clicking on item from the Table Layout?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a onclickListener to your row.

In order to identify wich cell was clicked you could tag the view of each cell using view.setTag(uniqueID) when you create it.

In your onClickListener function use view.getTag() to get the identity of your cell.